# URL/Link to sharepoint members group of subsite used as web template

Tags: 2013, groups, sub-site, web-template

Is there a simple way to create a link that points to the default "members" group of a subsite? I'm creating a subsite web template and would like to have a link for future site managers that goes directly to the subsite's members group page. Since this is a template a static url to the template's members group won't work. Is there a token or "dummy" url that always points to the default member group for a site?

Answer (score 0):

The webPart **Social Collaboration > Site Users** lists **all** Users and Groups with access to the site.
You can not filter display so forces you into good governance on access.

You can set the WebPart to display all users in the Members group, that will include an 'Add new user link'

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I have that one in place already, but I would like to create an easy link to the page for that group. I know it is only a few clicks to get to the full groups page but some of the end users for these sites won't be super familiar with Sharepoint. If possible I would like to link straight to the site's member group page so that users can add/remove people from the group or send messages to group members.

Comment: You can add JSOM or a REST call to get the *RoleAssignments* and proces and display them with some JavaScript code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the link `{site}/_layouts/15/people.aspx` will automatically redirect you to the members group, i.e. append the correct ID using the query parameter  `?MembershipGroupId=XYZ`